CLI Tool Fails to Recognize New Arguments During Direct Execution with Python-Fire
I'm working on a CLI in Python and I don't know why the main class of the CLI does not update as new arguments are added, performing the tool using python-fire.
I've mainly 2 scripts that rule the CLI: main.py and cli.py
main.py is structured as follows:
from src.cli import SearchFunction
import fire


def main_entrypoint():
    fire.Fire(SearchFunction)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_entrypoint()

While cli.py has the main class, where I've added the group argument:
class SearchFunction:

    @staticmethod
    def text_search(
        *keywords: str,
        type: Optional[str] = None,
        group: Optional[str] = None,  # NEW ARGUMENT
    ) -> None:
        """
        Perform a custom text search on the XXX website and save the results.

        :param keywords: List of keywords to search for
        :param type: Type of search
        :param group: group to search  # NEW ARGUMENT
        """
        if True:
            do_things()


If I run the tool using poetry:
poetry run edgar-tool text_search keywords to search for --type "type_1" --group "group_1" 

it correctly works with the new argument group.
Instead, with direct execution:
python main.py text_search keywords to search for --type "type_1" --group "group_1" 

returns:
ERROR: Could not consume arg: --group

Even clearing the __pycache__:
rm -r __pycache__

leads to the same result.
Why this does happen? How to make the direct execution updated with the edits that has been created?

You might want to make it very clear at the top of the content of your question as well as in the title of your question, that it is about python-fire.

@sinoroc Thaks for the suggestion, I've just added it!
